# Why is my Neural Net model giving 0% accuracy in machine learning with R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

This project aims to study bias detection and mitigation in machine learning algorithms for loan decisions using the dataset for home credit. The project's main aim is to build two machine learning models based on the dataset to predict clients' repayment abilities, where the predicted result 1 represents that the client has payment difficulties and 0 illustrates all other cases. I preprocessed the data and separated it into 3 sets: both genders, female, and male. Then I split each of those into 2 sets, training and testing. I then trained a neural net algorithm on each set then compared accuracy based around protected variable of gender. Right now I'm on the machine learning stage and am just trying to get an algorithm with above 0% accuracy. I'll include the code after this but right now I'm stuck at training portion. You can also view the code [here](https://github.com/littlejonjon99/R-ML-Project/blob/main/main.r). I may have preprocessed the data incorrectly somewhere but I can't tell. I am by no means a ML expert, but I have trained models before for smaller and simpler datasets like IRIS or similar smaller datasets. This dataset has 120 columns and 300k rows so it's not a small dataset but isn't that big.

**Small Snippet of The Code**

```
# TRAINING
nn_model <- nnet(TARGET ~ ., data = new_train, size = 2, maxit = 100, decay = 0.1) # nolint
nn_pred <- predict(nn_model, newdata = new_train)
nn_accuracy <- mean((nn_pred > 0.5) == new_train$TARGET)
#  TESTING
nn_test_pred <- predict(nn_model, newdata = new_test)
nn_test_accuracy <- mean((nn_test_pred > 0.5) == new_test$TARGET)
# Print accuracies
cat("Shallow Neural Net Accuracy on Train Data: ", round(nn_accuracy * 100, 4), "%", "\n",  sep = "") # nolint
cat("Shallow Neural Net Accuracy on Test Data: ", round(nn_test_accuracy * 100, 4), "%", "\n",  sep = "") # nolint
```

**What did I try and what was I expecting:**

- I originally didn't use any factors so i tried making previously character columns into factors
- Only scaling numerical columns instead of all columns
- Making the TARGET column factor type
- Trying fewer columns during ML training
- Changing number of units in the hidden layer
- Changing maximum number of iterations

Comment: While provided your code helps, it would also help to provide a reproducible dataset. Is it possible you are using the wrong loss function?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42410242/machine-learning-accuracy-shows-0?rq=2

Comment: The dataset is in the same [repository](https://github.com/littlejonjon99/R-ML-Project/tree/main). It was taken from Kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/data?select=application_train.csv). I'm not too familiar with loss functions but to my knowledge the loss function that the nnet package in R uses is the cross-entropy loss by default for binary classification problems (which should be used here). Would that be the problem? Should I just specify a different loss function when training it?